# receiving custom object as part of web api request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm exposing some data trough web api. Client is wpf application which consume this service in following way

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:11992/");

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 var url = "api/Data/;
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
           "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "myusername", "mypassword"))));                

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

on web api side code

```
 // GET: api/Data
 public IEnumerable<MyObject> Get()
 {
     return GetData().AsEnumerable();
 }
```

My question is:

is it possible to receive custom object as part of web api request so I can determine which computer with username accessing webservice?

Comment: You can either do it via the route/url and or querystring if its a simple value like an id e.g. `/api/entity/123` or `/api/entity/?id=123` or if it is a more complex object it is usually better to send a post request, where you can send json that gets deserialised into your class.

Comment: is that mean that I can use query string values for that puropse, like /api/entity/?username="john"&computername="old-Pc" ?

Comment: Yes, so long as your action method has the approprite signature e.g. `Get(string username, string computername)`. Btw don't quote your query string variables.  Use `/api/entity/?username=john` not `/api/entity/?username="john"`

Answer (score 0):

In short YES.

create a data contract

```
[DataContract]
public class MyRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string myString { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> myList { get; set; }
}
```

you can even use lists in the input and output.
If you use the `WebInvoke` attribute you can consume it with JSON.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
IEnumerable<MyResponse> MyGet(MyRequest request);
```

in this way you can do a post with JSON object and it works correctly just take care to put the correct content type `application/json` and to use the method `POST`.